# Cannot group by custom jekyll collection

Tags: filter, group-by, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to group elements from a [custom jekyll collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) by the value of one of their metadata (date).
So, I'm doing `{% for elt in site.my_collection | group_by: "date" %}` but it loops through the collection normally, just like I've written `{% for elt in site.my_collection %}`.

Even stranger is if I write in my template `{{ site.my_collection | group_by: "date" }}`, then it displays correctly the grouped collection `[{"name" => "day1", "items" => [#, #, #]}, {"name" => "day2", "items" => [#]}]`.

What am I doing wrong? Is this because I'm using a custom collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot `loop and sort/group` at the same time.

You have to `assign and sort/group` **then** `loop`

That's true for Jekyll elements like pages, posts or collection.

```
{% assign collection = site.my_collection | group_by: "date" %}

{% for group in collection %}
  <h3>{{ group.name | date: "%-d %B %Y" }}</h3>
  <ul>
    {% for item in group.items %}
    <li>{{item.data}}</li>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: how about group_by: 'year'

Comment: `group_by` works for any variable available in front matter. So, yes if you have a `year` variable in your collection's items, you can `group_by: 'year'`.